# LibGDX down is up and up is down Gdx.input.getY()

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm sure this is something very simple. I am having a major brain freeze. I have been inverting it, subtracting from it, multiplying to it, adding to it. No matter what up is down and down is up.

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)) s.drawCirc(c, Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 100, 100);
```

The x axis is fine the culprit is the `Gdx.input.getY()`. When I move my finger up it goes down and down it goes up.

My circle lines up in the middle but when I go up it goes down and when I go down it goes up. I would like to understand what exactly is going on here and why it is happening.(& of course how to fix it please)

In case you need to know `c` is my camera and here is the code in case this is the culprit

```
c = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

and in my `drawCirc` method I am using

```
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(c.combined);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the coordinate system used for input and the coordinate system used by the camera are opposite of each other on the y axis. Ideally when getting inputs, you want to unproject the input to the camera so that all of the coordinates are nicely aligned. You can do this using `c.unproject(input)`. Here's a code example:

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT))
{
  Vector3 input = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
  cam.unproject(input);
  //Now you can use input.x and input.y, as opposed to Gdx.input.getX() and
  //Gdx.input.getY(), to draw the circle
  s.drawCirc(c, input.x, input.y, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: How would I mathematically flip Y so it matches? I just want to know out of curiosity. Also for clarification LibGDX 0,0 is the bottom left corner? and OpenGL is the top left corner? Just trying to visualize this better.

Comment: OpenGL, and therefore the camera (which uses OpenGL), both have 0,0 in the bottom left. The input system, however, uses 0,0 at the top left. Since the camera can change scale and position, there's no easy mathematical way to transform between the two, so it's recommended you use the unproject method when transforming between the two. However, if your camera shows the entire world and isn't zoomed or transformed in any other way, simply using SCREEN_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY()  should do the trick. This isn't recommended though.

Comment: Is it okay to create a new Vector3 and unproject on every render event?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't cause any problems

Comment: Thank you for your help! I hope to see you stalking my questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX uses OpenGL which uses another coordinate system.

It uses left to right, bottom to top.

So in OpenGL 0,0 means bottom left corner.

Use 

`c = new OrthographicCamera();
c.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());`

First parameter means Y-Down

More information here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html

Check this link for more information about using LibGDX with down-y.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/YDownTest.java

Comment: Is there an equation I can do to the Y to make it correct without flipping everything upside down?